# Why is the vector about which the frame is rotated is given by: A r  = [ 0.707, 0.707, 0]T

Tags: vectors, robotics

[image: Question asked.]
Im querying why the vector which the frame is rotated is given by [0.707,0.707,0]. does equal distance have an impact etc

[image: answer]

Comment: $1/\sqrt 2 \approx 0.707$, if that helps.

Comment: By the way, where is this text from? It uses really strange notation for vectors, and uses approximations for square root of 2.

Comment: @BenjaminWang. is this the 45 degree thing where its cos(pi/4) = 1/root2

Comment: its from a robotics class. i wanna draw problem put but unsure how it looks. what way has the 30deg rotated about etc

Comment: Ask your teacher for the convention whether it's clockwise or anti-clockwise